# How to convert this screen session config to a similar config in tmux?

Tags: split, config, gnu-screen, tmux

Im attempting to switch from screen to tmux. One of my screenrc configs allows me to run vim (Im using NERD_tree + many vim splits) in most of the top horizontal portion of the screen, and keep a much smaller split window at the bottom for shell commands. Part of my screenrc dealing with splitting the window:

```
# start two sessions
screen -t code vim
screen -t shell
# goto screen 0 and split it
select 0
split
# switch to bottom split and make it 8 lines smaller
focus
resize -8
# select screen 1 to show in bottom split
select 1
focus
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a better alternative to my other answer is to use a shell script, reserving the configuration files for things like key bindings, status bar configuration, etc.

```
#!/bin/bash
tmux new-session -d -s coding-session -n code vim
tmux split-window -p 30
tmux attach-session -t coding-session
```

Here, we execute three tmux commands from the shell. The first creates a new session but does not attach to it (so that the process may exit). The second sends a `split-window` command to (presumably) the most recently created session. The third attaches the client to the named session.

Answer (score -1):

(Note: this is an improvement of my earlier answer)

We'll add the necessary tmux commands to a file named "vim-session". Let's look at the contents first, and then we'll see how to use the file.

```
new-session -n code vim
split-window
resize-pane -D 8
```

The first thing we do is create a new session. The `-d` prevents us from attaching to the session just yet, and the `-n` option names the session's initial window, in which we run `vim`. Next, we split the window vertically into two panes, one on top and one on bottom. The focus automatically moves to the new pane on the bottom. Finally, we resize the current pane downward (`-D`) by 8 lines.

You'll start your tmux session using

```
$ tmux -f vim-session attach
```

This says to use the configuration file we just created instead of the default file `~/.tmux.conf`. We give the explicit command `attach` to tmux so that it attaches to the session we created (but did not attach to) in "vim-session". Without `attach`, tmux would
implicitly create a new session and attach to that instead of the session we created in "vim-session".

By changing your resize criteria slightly, we can remove the call to `resize-pane`:

```
new-session -d -n code vim
split-window -p 30         # Make the new pane 30% of your screen
#split-window -l 10        # Make the new pane exactly 10 lines.
```

I don't think there is a way to have `split-window` create a new pane that is 8 lines smaller than half, though.

Comment: A lot of answers Ive seen usually involve having to create a separate file which you then have to source when starting tmux or from inside the session, otherwise you get a "can't establish session" error.
Would be nice to not need that extra file...

Comment: This seems to give me the exact same setup as screen, so thanks for that. BTW, the -f seems to imply that ~/.tmux.conf will get ignored right ? (Soon realised this after ^a stopped working as the hot key :-)

Comment: Right; that's probably the biggest reason to use the shell script in my other answer.